# Stored Procedure is not accepting values with ' and ò

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, officewriter

I have a problem with my SQL Stored Procedure when special characters are input. For example in my Home Country Filter, I have input "Còte D'Ivoire", and I cannot generate a Report/Result because of the "'" and "ò".

> Error: There were invalid inputs found on this page. Please make sure you've typed valid inputs.

Code:

```
IF  @DISPLAYCOUNTRYCD = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @SubClause = @SubClause + 'EPVW.CountryNm as COUNTRYCD,'
        SET @SelectClause = @SelectClause + 'COUNTRYCD as [Home Country],'
    END
```

Where the "EPVW" is the name of the Table, and CountryNm is the Column Name. It is retrieving values from that Table.

Please help.